# Model not populate with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I am new to Angular JS and stuck for long time on a particular issue.

For a UI Grid row , a column value would be in `linkcelltemplate`. And on click of that a Bootstrap Modal popup opens up and that has a `case quick search functionality`.

Here is the piece of code :

```
<div ng-controller="CaseSearchCtrl">
    <div ng-show="case.togglePleaseWait">
        <div class="refresh" style="padding:15px;width:100%;height:100px;">
            <h4>Please wait....</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            Case Search
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="selSearchType" id="selSearchType" class="form-control" ng-model="case.searchTerm"
                            ng-init="case.searchTerm == 'caseNo'" ng-options="o as o for o in case.searchTerms"></select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter search term" ng-model="case.input" /></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="case.quickSearch()">Quick Search</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the input text box we can enter a value and do a quick search.

[image]

Here is my controller piece of code :

```
TransactionModule.controller("CaseSearchCtrl", ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'TransactionServices', 'CaseServices', 'CaseDataServices', 'TransactionDataServices', function ($scope, $uibModal, TransactionServices, CaseServices, CaseDataServices,TransactionDataServices) {

    /* Case implementation starts*/
    $scope.case = {

        searchTerm: "caseNo",    
        searchTerms: caseSearchTerms(),
        toggleQuickSearch: true,
        togglePleaseWait: false,
        name: "",
        number: "",
        type: "",
        constName: "",
        userName: "",
        status: "",
    }

    $scope.case.quickSearch = function () {
        $scope.case.togglePleaseWait = true;

        console.log($scope.case.input);

        if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "caseNo") {
            $scope.case.number = $scope.case.input;
        }
        else if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "caseName") {
            $scope.case.name = $scope.case.input;
        }
        else if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "constituentName") {
            $scope.case.constName = $scope.case.input;
        }
        else if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "userName") {
            $scope.case.userName = $scope.case.input;
        }
        else if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "status") {
            $scope.case.status = $scope.case.input;
        }
        else if ($scope.case.searchTerm == "type") {
            $scope.case.type = $scope.case.input;
        }
        var postParams = [
         {
            "CaseId": $scope.case.number,
            "CaseName": $scope.case.name,
            "ReferenceSource" : "",
            "ReferenceId" : "",
            "CaseType": $scope.case.type,
            "CaseStatus": $scope.case.status,
            "ConstituentName": $scope.case.constName,
            "UserName": $scope.case.userName,
            "ReportedDateFrom" : "",
             "ReportedDateTo" : "",
            "UserId": $scope.case.userName
        }]

        console.log("Post params are");

        console.log(postParams);


        CaseServices.getCaseAdvSearchResults(postParams).then(function (result) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                $scope.case.togglePleaseWait = false;
                //constMultiDataService.setData(result, HOME_CONSTANTS.QUICK_CASE_SEARCH);
                console.log("Setting results for Quick search in TransactionDataServices");
                console.log(result);
             } ..........................
```

But here the `CaseInputSearchModel` while passing from the controller to web service is always `NULL` . But in the console I can see the list being passed.

```
getCaseAdvSearchResults: function (postCaseSearchParams) {
    console.log("Before sending to controller");
    console.log(postCaseSearchParams);
    return $http.post(BasePath + "CaseNative/AdvSearch", postCaseSearchParams, {
        //  return $http.post(BasePath + "Home/WriteCaseRecentSearches", postCaseSearchParams, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        $http.post(BasePath + "Home/WriteCaseRecentSearches", postCaseSearchParams, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result.data;
    });
},
```

[image]

Even though the parameters are logged in the console properly.

[image]

Here is how the Model to which I want the data to be bound looks like :

```
public class CaseInputSearchModel
{
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceSource { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string CaseType { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public string ConstituentName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ReportedDateFrom { get; set; }
    public string ReportedDateTo { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you map the results back into the model? I see you are manually mapping camelCase to PascalCase in the request. You may want to just use the JSON.Net CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

Comment: Could you open the Network tab in Chrome's console and check that the payload of the post request actually contains what you'd expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `[FromBody]` to the `AdvSearch` method does that fix it? Also, in the AdvSearch you have `ListCaseInputSearchModel` as the type.

`AdvSearch([FromBody] CaseInputSearchModel model)`

EDIT: 
Didn't notice you were sending an array. Try this method signature:

`AdvSearch([FromBody] IEnuermable<CaseInputSearchModel> model)`

Comment: To convert it to list only I am sending the json array. Should not it be mapped ?

Comment: Couldn't you just have `IEnumerable<CaseInputSearchModel>` as the type?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why List does not work ?

Comment: You're not mapping to the `ListCaseInputSearchModel`, you're mapping to an array of `CaseInputSearchModel`.  If you're asking if you can use `List<T>` yes you can.  Did that happen to fix your problem?

Comment: Yes somewhat but it breaks my service. How can I convert it to `ListCaseInputSearchModel` ?

Comment: What does `ListCaseInputSearchModel` look like? You would just make a JSON representation to match that model. So `postParams` would look like `var postParams = { "caseInputProperty": [ { "CaseId": 1, ... }] };`

Answer (score 1):

Ur model should have all the properties with same name as in postparams json...then only it will be mapped to it in controller... Is it having all the properties with same name.?

Comment: Please see the updated question. I have attached the Model Code.

Comment: Try Using json.stringify(postCaseSearchParams) while passing json to controller..